# How to extract data from a website without an api into an android app?

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio, networking

I am a little new to android programming. I want to make an android app that extracts data from some gaming websites but they don't have an api for getting data in json format. I know how to get data in json and how to parse it in android studio. So Is there any way to extract data from a website without an api . Please keep it descriptive because I am new to programming as I said earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descriptive is a bit complex. You can use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) library that let you fetch a website and to get variuos parts of DOM. It's very simple and use XPATH syntax to navigate through the DOM.

You can find an example on their homepage:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Then you must accomodate with what you need. Take in mind that this approach is not the best one because you are developing your logic basing it on website View, so if they change their View your code will fail.

Comment: I heard of API s that they would parse the data from your server to the clients of your app. I want to know what is the meaning of "Your Server" there ? Firyher, Can I have my own server that stores data from various gaming sites.

Comment: I think they are suggesting you to implement a server side application that parse remote gaming data. Then you could expose a service to call from your clients app. In this manner you should write and mantain only one parsing application (into your server)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you don't.  The best you can do is screen scrape-  download the website and try to parse it as html looking for specific areas of the screen.  The problem with this is anytime they change their html even a little bit, your app will break.  So its highly not recommended.  Instead I'd suggest you look for alternative sources of information that do have an API, or you scrap the idea.